# Moving selected cells UP/Down VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code moves the selected cells down in a table.

```
Sub MoveDown()
 Dim arr As Variant
 Dim r1 As Range
 Dim r2 As Range

 Set r1 = Selection
 If r1.Row + r1.Rows.Count - 1 = Rows.Count Then
    MsgBox "Bottom reached"
 Else
    Set r2 = r1.Resize(1).Offset(r1.Rows.Count)
    arr = r2
    r1.Offset(1) = r1.Value
    r1.Offset(1).Select
    r1.Resize(1) = arr
 End If
End Sub
```

The issue is that if the row below has "Annual Leave" in it, it will overwrite it and move the AL up to where the original selected top row was.

Also, if it moves down and it detects "Saturday" or "Sunday" in the "Weekday" column, then it should skip those rows. Note that if there is data in the Saturday Row, then it should not skip that row

Comment: What do you mean by "it will overwrite it and move the AL up to where the original selected top row was."? Not to move the respective cell value instead of the selection first cell? If so, it looks that the code you show does that **independent of the cells bellow selection value**... If not, please better describe how the code to behave in such a situation.

Comment: How do you want the code to behave when "skipping" the the weekend rows (row)? If, for instance, selection contains three cells, how this skipping to distribute them? The first selection cell to move down one cell, in their place coming the value after the weekend rows? If so, what to happen with the rest of the other two selection cells? Where to be placed? Will they overwrite  other cells **without moving their values above**? Or how? I think, you should edit your question and place some pictures showing before and after, for these not so clear cases...

Comment: Do you really need help? Do you exactly know what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I have just moved cells "A1:A3" to "A2:A4", while having the macro recorder running. It gave me following piece of source code:

```
Range("A1:A3").Cut Destination:=Range("A2:A4")
```

Good luck